# Setup Organization/Company subdomain in firebase without setting up DNS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, dns

I have an app hosted on firebase that is deployed to my Cloud Domains.

let's say `https://example.com`

Now, for every custom domain or subdomain I want to add to firebase, I require to manually setup the DNS on of my Cloud Domain with the required records.

But, I would like to create workspace for organization in my app (like for example Jira does doing myOrg.atlassian.com).

So the result would be

`organization.example.com`
`organization2.example.com`

Is it possible to allow this *without* having to manually set DNS for each organization joining our app ?

Would it be possible to dynamically create and setup on firebase and link those subdomain to my cloud domain ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to add custom domains automatically. [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest) doesn’t have such an API through which it can be done. Also I couldn’t find a workaround to dynamically achieve this feature. So the only way to do this is to go to the Firebase Console and set it up as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). You can go through this similar [StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532701/can-i-add-a-domain-to-firebase-hosting-via-the-api) to know more about it.