# How to setup custom domain for firebase hosting using firebase cli on CloudBuild

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

I currently have a running `CloudBuild` pipeline where I deploy an app to firebase hosting.

cloudbuild.yaml:

```
// omitted text

- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase
  args: ['deploy', '--project=$PROJECT_ID', '--only=hosting', '-m', 'Pipeline $BUILD_ID, committed by $_COMMIT_USER - $SHORT_SHA']

// omitted text
```

But I am unable to find out how to configure custom domain for the deployed app within the same cloudbuild.yaml or any other command-line way. on [google docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain), there is only a way to setup from firebase console.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no public API, nor a CLI command, to configure a custom domain name through Firebase Hosting. The only way to add a custom domain is indeed what you found, through the console.

It's a valid feature request though, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) with the support team and possibly also on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com).

---

Also see:

- [Can I add a domain to Firebase hosting via the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532701/can-i-add-a-domain-to-firebase-hosting-via-the-api)
- [Setup Organization/Company subdomain in firebase without setting up DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432943/setup-organization-company-subdomain-in-firebase-without-setting-up-dns)