# Firebase Admin SDK to interact with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-admin

I am building a web-app that will allow users to create their own domain and/or sub-domain to host their own templated website.  I can't find any reference for interacting with cloud hosting through the admin sdk or cloud functions.

Aside from using the firebase dashboard, how can we programmatically create and manage domains and hosting in Firebase?

Thank you!

-Tim

Answer (score 2):

There is a REST API for interacting with Firebase Hosting, but it is not wrapped in any of the Admin SDKs as far as I know. It is a valid feature request, so I recommend posting it on the Github repo of the Admin SDK you're using.

The best I've found is to look at how the Firebase CLI accesses the REST API, and replicate that in my own project. That's for example, how I created this code to [update a single file in an existing site](https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412).

Comment: Thank you for this info, I must have missed this in the docs. The sample you provided here looks very useful, so thanks for that as well!

Comment: Scanning through the docs I have not found a way to create and manage custom domains for these sites.  Have you found a way to manage these through the REST api?  Ideally I can create these TXT values programmatically. It appears that the only way to do this is through the hosting dashboard.

From my initial research, Firebase doesn't seem like the right platform for this service, but it's what I'm most comfortable with!

Comment: Ah, I missed where you asked specifically about domain management. There is indeed no API for managing domains yet. The commands available are all around commands like `firebase deploy --only hosting`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532701/can-i-add-a-domain-to-firebase-hosting-via-the-api

Comment: Too bad, that's unfortunate. I'll probably need to find another service for my webapp's hosting.  

I did submit that feature request for the Admin SDK.