# Is there a way to add a new site to my Firebase project without using the Console?

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, firebase-hosting

Is there a way for me to add/create a new site in my Firebase project in the same way I deploy new projects using the CLI.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532701/can-i-add-a-domain-to-firebase-hosting-via-the-api and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/projects.sites/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) has a [`firebase hosting:sites:create` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#hosting-commands) that looks promising. It looks like that wraps the corresponding [`/projects.sites/create` REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/projects.sites/create).

What doesn't seem possible at the moment (according to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532701/can-i-add-a-domain-to-firebase-hosting-via-the-api)) is to add a custom domain through the CLI or REST API. That is currently only possible through the Firebase console.